# How to parse the IIS response header "Date" in .NET

Tags: .net, datetime, httpwebrequest

I'm performing an HttpWebRequest against an IIS server.
One of the response headers is *Date*, which I'd like to parse.
This is its value:

```
"Sun, 11 Oct 2009 08:16:13 GMT"
```

How do I parase this string? DateTime.Parse didn't quite work out well for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I suppose that it would be a rather good idea to add a tag ".NET" to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `DateTime.TryParse`

```
var d = "Sun, 11 Oct 2009 08:16:13 GMT";
DateTime dt;
var b = DateTime.TryParse(d, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Outputs:

```
11-10-2009 01:46:13
```

Note: the time is little off the mark, I think it is being converted to local time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(loband).aspx) to specify the exact format you are attempting to parse. Without testing, it looks like you'll need:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss K");
```

Or, if the GMT gives you trouble, use the [DateTimeStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(loband).aspx) overload of [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038(loband).aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```